# CloudFront Distribution Domain status 301 redirect on custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I am trying to load all my static resources for my website using the Amazon CloudFront distribution. I have configured everything and I am able to load my files using the CloudFront domain URL.
But when I test speed in Gtmetrix.com or Pingdom tools shows me status 301.
I want status 200
location
https://www.example.com/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
server
Apache
**status    301**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eo5G.png)

x-cache Hit from CloudFront

Comment: I'm seeing a strange issue where CloudFront is incorrectly redirecting (301 Permanently!!) clients to the Origin server. Is that really the normal behavior of CloudFront?

Comment: i don't want this redirection x38etxfdbe.cloudfront.net 301 Moved Permanently example.com  200 OK
i want on cloudfront.net status 200

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Comment: Yes, I have resolved my issue with a lot of searching..

Comment: I'm still facing with this issue and pulling my hair... It'd be much appreciated if you could share your resolution with me/us. Thanks.

Comment: Yes i have resolved
don't add CNAME when you are creating distribution.